# How to concat a string with null in a postgres function with plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to write a function, witch selects some values from atable and then insert them into btable.

```
DECLARE
loRecord record;
loRTest record;
lsQueryExecute text;

BEGIN

SELECT INTO loRTest 
    1 as test1,
    0 as test2,
    NULL::int as test_fk1,
    NULL::timestamp as test_fk2,
    NOW() as teststamp,
    true as test_bool
FROM atable

raise notice 'result  % ', loRTest;
```

/* result  (1,0,,,"2020-01-29 11:28:33.785621+01",t) */

doing some stuff with the values and finaly inserting them into another table:

```
lsQueryExecute = 
'insert into btable (test1, test2, test_fk1, test_fk2, teststamp, test_bool) 
VALUES(
''' || loRTest.test1 || ''',
''' || loRTest.test2 || ''',
''' || loRTest.test_fk1 || ''',
''' || loRTest.test_fk2 || ''',
''' || loRTest.teststamp || ''',
''' || loRTest.test_bool ||''')';

/* EXECUTE */
 raise notice 'query  % ', lsQueryExecute; 

/*  query  <NULL>  */
```

well, concatenation with || and a *null* sets the whole string to *null*. Whats the correct (easy, nice ) way to concat the string (postgres 10)?

Comment: Use `CONCAT` function instead of `||`. It ignores NULL values (>9.6). If you are on <9.6, use `COALESCE(NULL, '')`.

Comment: There is a problem with possible sql injection, so don't do this without using `quote_literal` or `quote_nullable` functions, or use `USING` clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't concatenate the values, use proper placeholders

```
lsQueryExecute := 
  'insert into btable (test1, test2, test_fk1, test_fk2, teststamp, test_bool) 
   VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)';

execute lsQueryExecute 
  using loRTest.test1, loRTest.test2, loRTest.test_fk1, 
        loRTest.test_fk2, loRTest.teststamp, loRTest.test_bool;
```

If you need to generate dynamic SQL, the best way to do that is to use the `format()` function.

---

But why the dynamic SQL to begin with? You can do that with a single INSERT statement:

```
insert into btable
SELECT 1 as test1,
       0 as test2,
       NULL::int as test_fk1,
       NULL::timestamp as test_fk2,
       NOW() as teststamp,
       true as test_bool
FROM atable
```

---

If you can't use an INSERT...SELECT you still don't need dynamic SQL in your PL/pgSQL loop:

```
insert into btable (test1, test2, test_fk1, test_fk2, teststamp, test_bool) 
VALUES (loRTest.test1, loRTest.test2, loRTest.test_fk1, 
        loRTest.test_fk2, loRTest.teststamp, loRTest.test_bool);
```

Comment: thx, thats what im looking for. The dynamic SQL is for some manipulation and selecting some other records with the test_fks. i´ll try

Comment: @FatFreddy: that "manipulation" and selecting other rows could be done with expressions in the SELECT and joining to other tables. Don't do inefficient and slow single row inserts when you can do it with a bulk operation. But if you don't need dynamic column or table names, you don't need dynamic SQL

Comment: finished the task with your help, now its time for optimization:-)

Answer (score 2):

## Please avoid using Dynamic SQL from user input to prevent SQL injection. DO NOT USE BELOW IF INPUTS ARE UNTRUSTED.

In PostgreSQL, the `||` operator concatenates STRINGs but with a NULL argument the result is NULL.

### In PostgreSQL >= 9.1

Use the `CONCAT`/`CONCAT_WS` (With Separator) function instead of `||`. It will ignore `NULL` values.

`SELECT CONCAT('foo ', NULL, 'bar');` returns `foo bar`.

If you want a more **natural** result, use `CONCAT_WS`.
`SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', 'foo', NULL, 'bar');` returns `foo bar`. (**Notice the removed trailing space**)

### In PostgreSQL < 9.1:

You can combine `COALESCE` with the `||` operator like so:

`SELECT COALESCE('foo', '') || COALESCE(NULL, '') || COALESCE('bar', '');` returns `foobar`. You can adjust white-space according to your needs.

Comment: Attention - when is string used for dynamic SQL, then any variant of `concat` function is dangerous (due SQL injection).

Comment: Thanks @PavelStehule. Added a big black warning about it.

Comment: @AshharHasan - you should to expect so any text type input is untrusted. The vector of attach should be very different

Comment: @PavelStehule Absolutely agree. My answer would still be ok if the question was just about CONCAT instead of Dynamic SQL.